# Maven build path error

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, buildpath

I'm created a maven project using eclipse and it gives me following build path error

```
Description Resource Path Location Type Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/scjayasekara/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar' in project 'KromeSoop' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file BookStore       Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I remove the complete repository and update all projects in the workspace. But it didn't work either. any suggestions to solve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

I just replace spring web-mvc 4.1.1 dependency with spring web-mvc 4.1.3 and it solved the build path problem.